# Limit hover action to it's specfic children only jQuery 2.1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I'm trying to limit the hover action to it's specific child element.
i.e. 
when I hover over Image Here, only 1 million Team and wordpress should appear and when I hover over Image Here # 1, only 2 million Team and wordpress should appear.
[see link](http://jsfiddle.net/sherazahmed/p4jdfvrb/)

jQuery 2.1.3

```
    jQuery('doucment').ready(function () {
    jQuery('.b29_work_img').hover(function () {
        jQuery('.b29_work_hover').css({
            opacity: 0.8
        });
    }, function () {
        jQuery('.b29_work_hover').css({opacity: 0});
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <!-- our work -->
<div id="b29_our_work">
    <div class="b29_container">
        <div class="b29_row">
            <div class="b29_col b29_col_3 b29_work">
                <div class="b29_row">
                    <div class="b29_col b29_col_3 b29_work_img">
                         <h1>Image HERE</h1>

                        <div class="b29_work_hover">
                             <h4>1 Million Teams</h4>

                             <h5>Wordpress</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b29_col b29_col_3 b29_work_img">
                         <h1>Image HERE # 1</h1>

                        <div class="b29_work_hover">
                             <h4>2 Million Teams</h4>

                             <h5>Wordpress 4.3</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .b29_work_hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `jQuery('doucment').ready`. Document must not be a string, it must refer to `window.document`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your selector:

```
jQuery('.b29_work_hover', this)
```

or you can use `.find()` method:

```
jQuery(this).find('.b29_work_hover')
```

---

What is the issue?

1. `jQuery('doucment')` should be `jQuery(document)`
2. You are targeting all of the elements with `.b29_work_hover` class name.
3. You have not given the context of the selector which is `this`.

---

Note:

All the class selector in js like `document.getElementsByClassName("className")` or a library like jQuery `$(".className")` always returns a list of all the elements available on the page.

Comment: Ops, Sorry my Mistake, It worked perfect. Thanks Mate

Comment: `jQuery('doucment')` this shouldn't be in quotes and there is a typo in the keyword `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
jQuery('.b29_work_img').hover(function () {
        jQuery('.b29_work_hover').css({
            opacity: 0.8
        });
    }, function () {
        jQuery('.b29_work_hover').css({opacity: 0});
    });
```

by this:

```
jQuery('.b29_work_img').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).find(".b29_work_hover").css({
            opacity: 0.8
        });
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).find(".b29_work_hover").css({opacity: 0});
    });
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bq2kqnr/)

Basically you use `this` and `find` to find the element under the currently hovered element and change the opacity.

Comment: @GeeK only `jQuery(this).find()` has been added ;) And ur welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.b29_work_img:first').hover(function () {
    jQuery(".b29_work_hover:first").css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    jQuery(".b29_work_hover:last").css({
        opacity: 0.8
    });
});

jQuery('.b29_work_img:last').hover(function () {
    jQuery(".b29_work_hover:first").css({
        opacity: 0.8
    });
    jQuery(".b29_work_hover:last").css({
        opacity: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you serenesat! I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm quite not familiar with the structure and some functionalities. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I think you want to see that when you hover over one image, it's parent element should appear.

```
jQuery('doucment').ready(function () {
   jQuery('.b29_work_img').hover(
   function () {
     jQuery(this).children('.b29_work_hover').css({
        opacity: 0.8
     });
  }, 
 function () {
     jQuery(this).children('.b29_work_hover').css({opacity: 0});
  });
});
```